# Authing with AWSSDK.SecretsManager in .NET 4.6.2 on a local machine assuming a role

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I can't work out how to authenticate with secrets manager locally using a role. The examples I've seem to be using an old version of the nuget package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.SecretsManager/) or just use a root profile, I think.

I think my main issue is that the permissions have been added to a role rather than my root profile, so the default behaviour of reading from local aws config doesn't do the trick.

Comment: What exception/error you are getting?

Comment: @amitd I am getting "Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service". I have the .aws config in place that the VS extension created.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62061272/14843902) thread?

Comment: @amitd I have yee, seen that one, thanks though.