# Can a docker container get access to (not local) DynamoDB?

Tags: docker, amazon-dynamodb

I am learning about microservices and Docker and I have made a small application in visual studio 2022 that basically can perform CRUD operations on the DynamoDB (with ASP.NET 6.0).
When I run the project on localhost everything works, but as soon as I make a docker container and try to perform crud from the Docker container, I get an error that states:

```
unable to get iam security credentials from ec2 instance metadata service
```

I tried a bunch of things like changing my appsettings.json, but came to the conclusion that that is not the problem since it works when I run the solution locally.

When I google about this problem I get overflow with information about running DynamoDB locally. I get that that is good for developing purpose, but I still want to try to perform CRUD operations on my DynamoDB from the Docker container (and think it must be possible).

So my question is: is it possible to access my DynamoDB table from a Docker image?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. The problem was in my docker-compose file where I needed the following line:
volumes:
- ~/.aws/:/root/.aws:ro

I found it on this post:
[AWS DotNet SDK Error: Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60815037/aws-dotnet-sdk-error-unable-to-get-iam-security-credentials-from-ec2-instance-m)

by user @smcg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).