# Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service for .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aws-secrets-manager

I have a Windows service and I'm successfully able to get my AWS Credentials from the profile that is setup locally on the server.

However for the ASP.NET core API application that I have setup it keeps giving me the error

> Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service

I have added this to the `appsettings.json`

```
  "AWS": {
    "AWSProfileName": "myprofile",
    "AWSRegion": "myregion"
   }
```

In my startup class I have added this line entry

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(_config.GetAWSOptions());
```

Then in the code I'm using to get the secret I tried this (this works fine in my Windows Service Code)

```
    using (var client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
    {
        GetSecretValueRequest request = new GetSecretValueRequest();
        request.SecretId = name;
        request.VersionStage = "AWSCURRENT";
        var result = client.GetSecretValue(request);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomObject>(result.SecretString);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS DotNet SDK Error: Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60815037/aws-dotnet-sdk-error-unable-to-get-iam-security-credentials-from-ec2-instance-m)

Comment: It's working in debugging mode if I change the using from new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1)) to => (var client=new AmazonSecretsManagerClient()) instead of the region endpoint but it doesn't work when I deploy it to the server.

Answer (score -1):

1. Must install your machine whether server or development AWS CLI and configure region and user credential at that time that is work other wise you should bind Credential and secret of that IAM User.